# How can I plot this function in Mathematica for different values of $a, b$

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

```
Prem[a_, b_] := 
  Integrate[(Gamma[a + b]/(Gamma[a]*Gamma[b]))*
    Integrate[
     Integrate[u^(a - 1)*(1 - u)^(b - 1), {u, 0, x}], {x, 0, 
      tailG[x]}], {x, 0, Infinity}];
data = {Prem[0.5, 1], Prem[0.6, 1], Prem[0.7, 1], Prem[0.8, 1], 
  Prem[0.9, 1], Prem[1, 1], Prem[0.5, 2], Prem[0.6, 2], Prem[0.7, 2], 
  Prem[0.8, 2], Prem[0.9, 2], Prem[1, 2], Prem[0.5, 3], Prem[0.6, 3], 
  Prem[0.7, 3], Prem[0.8, 3], Prem[0.9, 3], Prem[1, 3], Prem[0.5, 4], 
  Prem[0.6, 4], Prem[0.7, 4], Prem[0.8, 4], Prem[0.9, 4],
  Prem[1, 4], Prem[0.5, 5], Prem[0.6, 5], Prem[0.7, 5], Prem[0.8, 5], 
  Prem[0.9, 5], Prem[1, 5]}

ListLinePlot[data]

Plot[{Prem[a, b],Prem1[a,b]},Prem2[a,b]}, {x, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

for a<1 and b>1 i want to plot and then include more that two functions in the some plot

Comment: What is  `tailG`?

Comment: tailG[x_] := Exp[-(1/2)*x]; is survival function

Comment: what is Prem[]?

Comment: Please add definitions of these quantities to your question instead of providing them in  comments.

Comment: its my function

Comment: `Plot`(and similar) can accept a list of functions to plot, and will plot them all on the same graph. E.g. something like `Table[Prem[a,bconstant], {a,a0,a1,da}]~Join~Table[Prem[aconstant,b],{b,b0,b1,db}]` might help—it's hard to tell without more details as to what exactly you want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to plot that 3D-integral depending on the parameters `a,b`.
Let us do it step by step (Two small steps are better than one big step.).
First, we calculate

```
Gamma[a + b]/(Gamma[a]*Gamma[b])*Integrate[u^(a - 1)*(1 - u)^(b - 1), {u, 0, x}, 
Assumptions -> a > 0 && a < 1 && b > 1 && x >= 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(Beta[x, a, b]*Gamma[a + b])/(Gamma[a]*Gamma[b]), x < 1]`

Second, we make the next integration (The upper bound of the integration is redesignated from `Exp[-x/2]` to `Exp[-y/2]` to avoid
any misunderstanding.)

```
Integrate[(Beta[x, a, b] Gamma[a + b])/(Gamma[a] Gamma[b]), {x, 0, Exp[-y/2]}, 
Assumptions -> a > 0 && a < 1 && b > 1 && y >= 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(Gamma[a + b]*Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[a, 1 - b, 2 + a, E^(-1/2*y)])/ (E^(((1 + a)*y)/2)*Gamma[b]), && y > 0]`

In the above Mathematica blows on cold water by `NotElement[b, Integers]` (see that follows). It's clear
there is no chance to symbolically integrate the latest expression by `y`, so

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[NIntegrate[(Gamma[a + b]* Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[a, 1 - b, 2 + a, 
E^(-1/2*y)])/(E^(((1 + a)*y)/2)*Gamma[b]), {y, 0, Infinity}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5]], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me but in my mathematica doesnt run this graph

Comment: I use 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho5sp0fwra7mwzt/plot18.05.21.pdf?dl=0) is the executed code exported as PDF. .nb file on demand through Dropbox. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.